# Phaser 3: "Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost." warning and memory leak

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm testing phaser for memory leaks by creating and destroying many instances using interval: `setInterval(this.createCharts, 1000);`

Game config:

```
  const PHASER_CONFIG: GameConfig = {
    type: Phaser.WEBGL,
    width: 1200,
    height: 400,
    parent: "chart-app",
    backgroundColor: "#232327"
  };
```

Method itself for creating/destroying instances:

```
  // createCharts: if charts are already initialized - destroy all, otherwise - create (allChart is holding active instances)
public createCharts() {
  if (this.allCharts.length > 0) {
    let i = this.allCharts.length;

    while (i--) {
      this.allCharts[i].destroy(true);
      this.allCharts[i] = null;
      this.allCharts.splice(i, 1);
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let chart = new Phaser.Game(PHASER_CONFIG);
      this.allCharts.push(chart);
    }
  }
}
```

App memory footprint is steadily growing, and I'm seeing console warnings for each new Phaser.Game - "WARNING: Too many active WebGL contexts. Oldest context will be lost."

Not sure if there's an error with my code, or maybe I'm not properly destroying phaser instances.